# NSURLSessionDataTask when running in background remote notification with content_available =1

Tags: ios, background, notifications, push-notification, nsurlsession

My app is sending notifications (like a chat app) that inform the other app that it needs to fetch the message from the server even when it's not in the foreground.

I plan an APN to send notification with `Content_available=1` and then have the app to call the server to get new messages.

My question is,

- Will `didReceiveRemoteNotification` get called always, as long as it's running in the background)?
- I do not intend to use Background transfer service but make the fetch call in the `didReceiveRemoteNotification` delegate?
- Any concerns about using `NSURLSessionDATATask` to achieve this (as opposed to the `NSURLSessionBackgroundTask`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A background push will never be delivered if the user has explicitly terminated the app.

Apart from that, background pushes were reliable (though not 100% guaranteed) up until 8.1.

With iOS 8.1 onwards background pushes are only delivered to the app immediately after being sent if the device is being charged. Otherwise the app might not receive the push till a few or several hours later.

Thus background pushes are now useless if you need the app to get notification of the new message within a short time of the message becoming available.

I and many others are hoping this may change in iOS9 but I'm not feeling optimistic.

Comment: are referring with "background push"  to remote notifications with content available=1? please elaborate. ty

Comment: Yes that's what Im referring to

Comment: I understand that the time it takes for APN to deliver messages is indeterministic but in my tests push notification does get delivered within a few minutes.

Comment: I find its usually just a few seconds. But with the later versions of iOS it just won't get delivered usually for a few hours if the device isn't being charged (directly, or via usb connection). This is only for background pushes, not foreground pushes. If you want to test it yourself you must use the production environment to evaluate it, the development environment behaves differently. With the dev environment the pushes will get delivered within a few seconds/minutes, this won't happen with production.

Comment: Check out this thread on the apple forums https://devforums.apple.com/message/1092217

Comment: sounds like i should not be using content_available=1 but send the payload with the remote notification? i guess that a remote notification with payload is ht way to go. your thoughts?

Comment: We see the same behavior as Gruntcakes.  Notifications often arrive at the phone and appear in Notification Center, but the app is still not woken up.

Comment: Depends on your app requirements and the user experience you want or don't want. Its the content_available flag that makes it a silent/background push. If you take that away it turns into a regular push. If your app isn't in the foreground when a regular push arrives then the push will be displayed to the user, and you will only get access to the payload if the user taps on the notification.

Comment: Also, Apple document that notifications may be coalesced (old notifications dropped) by APNS if notifications cannot be delivered to the phone immediately. We actually don't see this (much or at all) and APNS seems to be queuing more notifications than they say that they will.  But I wouldn't rely on that in the long term.  Expect notifications to go missing, and design for that.

Comment: With iOS7 things were ok, but at the moment unless Apple change something, with iOS8 there is effectively NO  way for an app to be notified by a server to pull content, or for the app to poll and pull stuff from a server if its a requirement that the content is fetched "quickly".

Comment: If iOS could sit on a push notification for a significant span of time  before allowing app to refresh in the background, then silent notification seems useless for "messaging" type functionality. I am guessing Apple designed the silent notification feature for apps that need to download large files (pictures etc.) and the timeliness of making content available on the device is of no consequence.